# How to set font to the label in launch Screen in iOS 8

Tags: ios

How can we set font to a label in launch Screen, i have tried of setting custom fonts through storyboards. The font is applied and seen in the storyboard but when i launch the app i am not able to see the font applied.

How to overcome this problem.

Comment: Are you making changes in _LaunchScreen.xib_ file or in _Main.storyboard_? Because launch screen have a separate xib from storyboard, so make sure you are applying changes at right place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though it may appear like you can in Xcode 6, you can't specify a custom font for the launch screen, since the launch screen is shown before your fonts load. Create an image of your text and use that.

Answer (score -3):

@kool kims,

its simple,
Directly go to **LaunchScreen.xib** then Select Label & Change its Property From Right side of Menu ..

//For More Click Link to See -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrRPM.png

Comment: I tried same but when i launch the app on my iPhone the font is not applied on label but on the xib it is seen as if the font is applied, i am totally confused why the font is not applied to the label.

Answer (score -5):

[image: Launch file]

You need add .xib file how Launch Screen File and add your design to it.